# Why does dot sourcing a powershell script fail, but just running the same script work?

Tags: powershell

I am having trouble running the following extract of code from a power shell script

G:\RUN_FULL_CAPTURE.ps1

```
$scriptToRunPath = "${scriptDrive}:\CAPTURE_SCRIPTS\STAGE_3\copy-unattend-file-to-recovery-partition.ps1"
$scriptToRunArgs = "-edition ${edition} -recoveryDriveLetter ${recovery_drive} -ErrorAction silentyContinue"
$scriptToRunPathWithArgs = "${scriptToRunPath} ${scriptToRunArgs}"
Write-host $scriptToRunPathWithArgs
if((Test-Path -Path $scriptToRunPath) -eq $true) {
    Write-Host "Running copy-unattend-file-to-recovery-partition.ps1..."
    . $scriptToRunPathWithArgs
}
```

Output (of the complete script) is:

```
.: G:\RUN_FULL_CAPTURE.ps1:53
Line |
  53 |      . $scriptToRunPathWithArgs
     |        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The term 'G:\CAPTURE_SCRIPTS\STAGE_3\copy-unattend-file-to-recovery-partition.ps1 -edition HOME
     | -recoveryDriveLetter R -ErrorAction silentlyContinue' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script
     | file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
     | correct and try again.
```

Running the script contained in $scriptToRunPathWithArgs (G:\CAPTURE_SCRIPTS\STAGE_3\copy-unattend-file-to-recovery-partition.ps1 -edition HOME -recoveryDriveLetter R -ErrorAction silentlyContinue) in powershell results in:

```
scriptDrive is: G
Path OK
usbDrive is: E:
Path not found
Path not found
Path not found
Path not found
Path not found
Path not found
Path not found
Path not found
Path OK
captureDrive is: G:
Path not found
Path not found
Path not found
Path not found
usbrive is: E:
captureDrive is: G:
PEFirmwareType: AMD64
bootMode: UEFI
edition is: HOME
sourcePath: E:\custom_installation_media_files\unattended_files\for_custom_recovery_partition\uefi\home\autounattend.xml
destinationPath: R:\autounattend.xml
recoveryDriveLetter: R
unattend.xml file exists on recoveryDrive, file won't be copied.
```

As you can see, running "copy-unattend-file-to-recovery-partition.ps1" from powershell does not result in any errors. So why does dot sourcing the same script from another powershell script fail?

I tried adding "-ErrorAction silentlyContinue" to the end of $scriptToRunPathWithArgs, the script "G:\RUN_FULL_CAPTURE.ps1" still fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **`.`**, the [dot-sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-) - as well as **`&`**, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-) call operator - **expects only a *command name/path* as an argument, not a full *command line*** - any pass-through arguments must be specified *separately*.
- Additionally, you **cannot encode *multiple arguments* inside a *single string***.

  - **Use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting) to pass programmatically construct arguments**, as shown below.

---

```bash
$scriptToRunPath = "${scriptDrive}:\CAPTURE_SCRIPTS\STAGE_3\copy-unattend-file-to-recovery-partition.ps1"

# Construct a hashtable for the pass-through arguments
# that you can use with splatting.
$scriptToRunArgs = @{
  edition = ${edition}
  recoveryDriveLetter = ${recovery_drive}
  ErrorAction = 'silentyContinue'
}

if (Test-Path -Path $scriptToRunPath) {
    Write-Host "Running copy-unattend-file-to-recovery-partition.ps1..."
    # Note the use of @ rather than $, to perform splatting.
    . $scriptToRunPath @scriptToRunArgs
}
```

Comment: Your answer just posted a second or two before my own answer. You hit the nail on the head. I think your solution is an improvement on mine.

Answer (score 0):

I have rewritten the code block in G:\RUN_FULL_CAPTURE.ps1

It now reads:

```
# copyUnattendFile
# Copy unattend.xml file to the recovery partition
$scriptToRunPath = "${scriptDrive}:\CAPTURE_SCRIPTS\STAGE_3\copy-unattend-file-to-recovery-partition.ps1"
if((Test-Path -Path $scriptToRunPath) -eq $true) {
    Write-Host "Running copy-unattend-file-to-recovery-partition.ps1..."
    . $scriptToRunPath -edition $edition -recoveryDriveLetter $recovery_drive 
}
```

The problem was that powershell was treating the contents of  $scriptToRunPathWithArgs as a path and failing. As you can see in the above code block the arguments I wanted to run before have been removed from  $scriptToRunPathWithArgs. The arguments have been added to the end of the dot sourcing line.